# Drools: Unable to find compatible version of drools and decision-table for java 18

Tags: drools, java-18

We are using drools and decision-table(6.2.0.Final) with java 8 since long time and it is working fine.
Now we have updated java version to 18 and with older version of drools(6.2.0.Final) we are getting error
*Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module*

Then we updated drools to latest final version(7.73.0.Final) and then we start are getting new error.
*There already exists an implementation for service org.kie.api.io.KieResources with same priority 0*

Then we tried with 8.26.0.Beta version of drools, with this we are able to create KieSession but we we fire our rule we are setting global (kSession.setGlobal) and there are we getting *"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global"*
We double checked in excel file we have declared variables for updating globals.

So basically I have tried various version of drools with java 18 but unable to find compatible version.

Comment: You're changing a lot of variables all at once. Do you have a working version of your app on a (relatively) recent version using an older version of Java?

Comment: Java 17 works with Drools 7.x in my apps, and 18 isn't that much different. The errors you're getting sound more like they're issues with your code/rules which is why I'm curious about whether the app works with a slightly older JDK.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes my app was working since long time with java 8 and drool(6.2.0.Final). I started facing issue moment I update java version to 18.

Comment: One important thing we are using decision table instead of drl file directly. So we read all our rules from excel.

Comment: I asked if it still functions with a modern version of drools. 6.2 is 7 years old.

Comment: No it is not working with modern version of drools.

Comment: So the problem is with your app and not the java version. If you can get it working with a modern version of drools and Java 8, then you should be able to swap over to Java 18 (or another newer flavor) without issue.